# How to accès images from drawable folder?

Tags: android

Im trying to create gallery application. In tutorial I've found, I need to do get images using R.drawable.image_name. I've created folder drawable under /res folder, copied my images one by one into that folder, al of them are .png. But when I try to access them by writing R.drawable.image I can't do that because there is no images I've copied. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Clear and rebuild your project. If you got automatic builds disabled, your IDE will not refresh `R` class contents and won't autocomplete your assets IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Do clean build or if you are using android studio do invalidate cache and make project afterwards.

For Accessing Drawable:

```
Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_name);
```

If you want bitmap :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.image_name);
```

if you want to access by url :

```
imgUrl= "drawable://" + R.drawable.image_name;
```